# Monitoring HP and Dell hardware in Gentoo

Tags: linux, monitoring, hardware, gentoo, hp-proliant

I'm working in an environment that features a large number of Gentoo servers running on HP ProLiant and Dell PowerEdge equipment. While I've moved some of these systems to RedHat or CentOS for consistency, I'm still left with a good number of systems that will remain Gentoo.

One of the issues I see with the Gentoo arrangement is lack of vendor-supported hardware monitoring. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the HP ProLiant Support Pack or Dell's agents for Gentoo. Is this simply something that you give up when using this distribution? How do *you* monitor hardware health and the like with Gentoo systems?

Comment: A better question. Is Gentoo even considered to be enterprise worthy anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was unable to locate it in a brief search, I will assume that an rpm package is available for both hardware platforms.

```
emerge --sync && emerge -pv rpm
```

Depending on your USE flags this will be a list of packages of varying length. Inspect the list to be sure that compile options and packages look correct then

```
emerge -av rpm
```

Once installed, you will be able to use the rpm package manager as you do on any Red Hat-based distribution.

Obviously this path will result in accepting the prebuilt compile options for the rpm package(s), but presumably these are acceptable if you are already using the software for Red Hat systems.

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing rpm's in Gentoo. Once did it, and it should be possible.

Also, I think it's a good idea to ask this question in Gentoo forums.

If you're not working for Hyves.nl, you might try to contact some sysadmin there and friendly ask them this question as it's the biggest (web)site running on Gentoo I'm currently aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware monitoring agent don't have the source code? Only rpm? You can 'convert' the rpm file to .tar.gz and try installing in Gentoo.